# Generate vector from another vector using a vector of indices

Tags: arrays, r, vector

I have a vector in R like this

```
a = c(5,7,8)
```

And I want to generate a vector of its elements using a vector that indicates the elements' position in `a`, e.g.

```
b = c(1,1,1,3,3,2,2,2,2)
```

which should result in

```
5 5 5 8 8 7 7 7 7
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `[` with 'b' as index

```
a[b]
#[1] 5 5 5 8 8 7 7 7 7
```

Answer (score -1):

b = c(a[1],a[1],a[1],a[3],a[3],a[2],a[2],a[2],a[2])

or

b = c(rep(a[1],3),rep(a[3],2),rep(a[2],4))

Comment: While this may work in the OP's specific situation, this is a very manual approach and thus isn't scalable. What if `a` had 200 elements and the vector of indices had 1000?

Comment: `b` is already defined in the OP, so you probably want to call the output something else (not `c`, though).